# discord.py bot getting error: Client.run() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Trying to code a discord python bot using IDLE but I am getting the error:
**TypeError: Client.run() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given**

Please can someone explain what I am doing wrong and how to fix it? Using Python version 3.10.7

*Code:*

```
import discord

TOKEN = '[Removed for privacy]'

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))



client.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: What version of discord.py are you running, and could include the full stacktrace? In all modern versions of dpy, `client.run` takes 2 positional arguments.

Comment: Ah I think the issue is that discord recently released a discord.py version 2.0.0 which means following old tutorials is causing errors

Comment: No, in discord.py 2.0 you still need to pass the token as a positional argument. That makes two positional arguments (including `self`)

Comment: @TheFungusAmongUs I am using the most recent version and the stack trace gave:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\(myname)\Desktop\bot\test.py", line 13, in <module>
    client.run(TOKEN)
TypeError: Client.run() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: so when you `print(discord.__version__)`, what do you get? If it was the latest version, you'd get an error when trying to define `client` with no intents

Comment: oh it says 0.9.2, now I am even more confused

Comment: If you do `pip freeze` in the terminal of the environment you're in, do you see `discord.py`, or some other library?  If you see discord.py, you should upgrade to the newest version.